# After successful connection with local mysql database in SlashDB, not able to see the database tables and all?

Tags: api, slashdb

Configured the mysql database related changes and connection established successful but still not able to see the tables from that Db for further operation??

Comment: You need to supply us with more details, like some basic info on the schema and table ownership, and also how you are attempting to query the database. Show relevant commands and output. Details about DB versions would be useful, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

SlashDB will only "see" tables, for which the user has at least SELECT privileges. Try the schema owner for username/password in the database configuration dialog.

Also make sure that your "admin" user has been mapped to a database login with sufficient privileges for those tables. This mapping is done on the Configuration->Users screen. This is different than the database config screen and allows you to define different API users with different privileges to data. The "admin" is no exception here.

Finally, SlashDB will be only reflect into API tables, which have a primary key defined. In absence of the actual primary key it is possible to override it in /etc/slashdb/databases.cfg using the "alternative_keys" setting. I don't have this handy right now, but I will post an update this answer with an example later.

If you do edit any config files by hand you will need to restart the service.

```
sudo service slashdb stop
sudo service slashdb start
```

Comment: Here's relevant part in the docs https://docs.slashdb.com/user-guide/config-users.html

Comment: Let me know if  you still need help or accept the answer. Thanks.